# Delta distribution is not induced by and tempered function

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

Call a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ a $\textit{tempered}$ function if there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| \, (1+|x|)^{-N} < \infty.$$ Then it is known that the $\textit{tempered distribution}$ induced by $f$, $$T_f: \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$$ $$T_f(\phi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx$$ is indeed a tempered distribution, where $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of Schwartz functions and a tempered distribution has the property that if $\phi_j \to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, then $T_f(\phi_j) \to 0$ . I would like to show that the (a priori) tempered distribution  $$\delta: \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$$ $$\delta(\phi) = \phi(0)$$ is not induced by any tempered function $f$.

My argument is intuitively clear to me, but the rigor in some steps, I am not sure.

On the contrary, suppose that we have some $f$ so that $T_f = \delta$. Let $\varphi$ be some symmetric bump function such that $\mathrm{Supp}(\varphi) \subseteq [-1,1]$ and $\varphi(0) = 1$. Define a sequence $\varphi_j = \varphi(jx)$. Then for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$\delta(\varphi_j)=\delta(\varphi(jx)) = \varphi(0) = 1.$$ Thus $\delta(\phi_j) \to 1$. On then other hand, since $\mathrm{Supp}(\varphi_j) = [-1/j, 1/j]$ we have $$T_f(\varphi_j) = \int_{-1/j}^{1/j} f(x) \varphi_j(x) dx$$ so that $T_f(\varphi_j) \to 0$.

By uniqueness of limits we must have $T_f \neq \delta$.

Comment: Your argument is quite rigorous.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy . I do not have much analysis background before this class, in particular I know very little about lesbegue integration and measure theory. I was unsure that my justification for T_f $/to$ 0 I was unsatisfied with.

Comment: Also I did not use my hypothesis that $f$ was tempered, since I didn’t use the tempered property of $T_f$ which I found worrisome

Comment: @PrinceM the dirac distribution isn't induced by any locally integrable function. This is more than you set out to prove, but its still right (and what you proved)

Comment: @PrinceM Hi M, as Calvin comments, the Dirac distribution isn't induced by any locally integrable function. And actually what you prove is exactly this statement. Because you choose your test functions as a family of bump functions which are supported in a common compact set, i.e. $[-1,1]$, it suffices to let your $f$ be locally integrable in order to make the mapping $T_f$ well defined.